# How to remove .plist from library-preference folder in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, encryption, sandbox, preference

When I run my app I figure out that in library-preference, Xcode generates the .plist that everyone can see and also can modify. I found out the way how to remove the cache, but how could I write in objective-C to not generate .plist file in preference folder?

Comment: Why do you want to remove this file(s)?

Comment: ios or macos? why encryption tag?

Comment: Hi @Willeke, in my app there is some confidential data that when it run, it shows in preference - .plist file (like server URL). What I want is just delete it Or to not generate this file.

Comment: Hi @mahal tertin, it is for IOS, I tag encryption that if there is no way to not delete the file maybe there should be a way to encrypt the file.